# Google Sheets query where not working with cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I use the query function to extract data from my tables in google sheets. But one of the conditions must be a reference to another cell. I do it like this:

```
=QUERY(Orig!A:Z;"select F where D= '"&C2&"' ";-1)
```

But it finds no coincidences. However, if I put the content of cell C2 directly in the query like this it works:

```
=QUERY(Orig!A:Z;"select F where D=3400 ";-1)
```

the data in D that I use for the select is numeric, and also the data in the reference cell C2. I tried casting to text, but nothing worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the source (**C2**) is number your query needs to look like this:

```
=QUERY(Orig!A:Z; "select F where D="&C2; -1)
```

otherwise, you would need to do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(Orig!A:Z); "select Col6 where Col4='"&TO_TEXT(C2)&"'"; -1))
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I'm a little slow today... I actually did this before